# Improving script performance for looping unparalleled arrays

Tags: javascript, optimization

Ive written a script to loop through a couple of unparalleled arrays a loop within a loop, Now im trying to find out if using `break` is all that's needed to exit and then continue over again.

What eles can you see or know to improve this?

```
var arr_vals = ["74","f4e3","22","r31","17","hundernds"]; // could have 500+ items
var arr_items = ["r31","22","65","100"]; // could have 50 items

var c = arr_items.length;
var arr_vals_len = arr_vals.length;
 for ( var i = 0; i < c; i++ ) { 
   var xid = arr_items[i];

     for (var j = 0; j < arr_vals_len; j++ ){
      if(arr_vals[j] === xid){
      // match !
      break;
}
 }
```

Comment: `break` will break out of the inner loop but not the outer one, so it will continue with the next iteration of the outer loop. Is that what you're asking? Also, I think you mean `var j` rather than `var r`.

Comment: @seand yes that's right, and r is supposed to be j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the inner array multiple times, it might be faster to create a map for the inner array beforehand and then test for a match within the map. (I think this will only work if they're arrays of strings, though.)

```
var arr_vals = ["74","f4e3","22","r31","17","hundernds"]; // could have 500+ items
var arr_items = ["r31","22","65","100"]; // could have 50 items

var vals_len = arr_vals.length;
var items_len = arr_items.length;

var map_items = {};
for(var j = 0; j < items_len; ++j) {
  map_items[arr_items[j]] = 1;
}

for( var i = 0; i < vals_len; ++i) {
  if(map_items[arr_vals[i]]) {
    // match!
  }
}
```

[Perf test](http://jsperf.com/map-vs-array)